# what is the difference between Application Server and Web Server in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, webserver, application-server

what is the difference between Application Server and Web Server in Java?
please let me know about this and have some examples from them.

Comment: Web server is not EJB-container.

Answer (score 2):

A web server isn't specific to Java.  It is simply a server for hosting content accessed via HTTP/HTTPS. Examples would be Apache HTTPD and nginx.

A Java application server actually hosts and executes Java application code. Examples include servlet containers such as Apache Tomcat, Jetty, etc. and Java EE containers such as J